# Ngrx reducer stop hitting even though state is correctly set

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a simple state

```
{
 items: Item[]
 selectedItems: string[]
}
```

I have a list of items with checkboxes where when i select an item the list state is updated with the correct selected items.
The problem is that at some point I go deeper into the item to edit it.

After the edit is done i navigate back to the list and I can correctly see the appropriate state with the selected items still there.

Now i try to deselect an item but the reducer appears to do nothing.
Reducer looks like this

```
  on(addItemToSelection, (state, { id, checked }) => ({
    ...state,
    selectedItems: checked ? [...state.selectedItems, id] : state.selectedItems.filter((itemId) => itemId !== id)
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

If selectedItems is of Type String[] - the following Code can't work:

```
state.selectedItems.filter((item) => item.id !== id)
```

because you don't have a Property called 'id' on your selectedItems which is just and String-Array.

Instead try:

```
state.selectedItems.filter((item) => item !== id)
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried your Code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-peynmr) and it works just fine.

Comment: yes. please don't take that into account. i edited the post. problem persists

Comment: the problem is not in the state it self. The state is correct before and after i finish with the edit of the item.
The problem happens when after editing and navigating back to my list and even though I can see the action dispatched with the correct parameters the reducer does not do anything. While before finishing the edit(was in the list) the reducer worked as expected